# Multiple Camera Component react-native-camera

Tags: android, ios, react-native, camera, react-native-camera

I have an app, with three screens, where you can swipe left and right to go to other screens. Each screen should have a camera as background and some buttons. When I use camera component of react-native-camera. It works great for single screen. But when include camera component in all three views. The screen goes white.

Here is the Swiper Code:

```
<Swiper showsPagination={false} loop={false} index={1}>
    <MessageSection/>
    <PhoneSection/>
    <DocumentSection/>
  </Swiper>
```

And here is the phoneSection:

```
<Camera
      ref={(cam) => {
        this.camera = cam;
      }}
      style={global.COMMON.container}
      aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
    <View style={[global.COMMON.container, {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]}>
      {backButton}
      <View style={global.COMMON.centerView}>
        <Animatable.Text animation="fadeOut" delay={2000} style={[global.COMMON.centerText, {color: 'white'}]}>Place a call to Contacts and Service Providers</Animatable.Text>
      </View>
      <View style={global.COMMON.bottomSection}>
        {buttonSection}
      </View>
    </View>
  </Camera>
```

The code looks similar in other components as well. But once I use more than one camera component. The camera doesn't function it only shows white screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem. The trick is to use single camera component instead of three.

I solved the problem by making the Camera component my main component and adding the swiper component inside it. So, everything else is on top of camera. Which allows you to create anything on top of it.

```
<Camera
      ref={(cam) => {
        this.camera = cam;
      }}
      style={global.COMMON.container}
      aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
  <Swiper showsPagination={false} loop={false} index={1}>
    <MessageSection/>
    <PhoneSection/>
    <DocumentSection/>
  </Swiper>
</Camera>
```